# Floating point result discrepancy between two seemingly identical statements

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got the following Visual Basic code:

```
    Dim L16, L23, L45, t As Double
    Dim LBase, LAdjacent, LOpposite As Double

    L16 = 20
    L23 = 10
    L45 = 30
    t = 1

    LBase = L16
    LAdjacent = L23
    LOpposite = L45

    Dim Sum As Double

    Sum = t ^ 2 * L16 + 6 * t ^ 3 + 2 * L16 ^ 3 + 3 * L16 ^ 2 * t + 2 * L23 ^ 2 * L16 + L23 ^ 2 * t + 8 * L23 * t * L16 + 4 * L23 * t ^ 2 - L45 ^ 2 * L16 + L45 ^ 2 * t - 4 * L45 * t * L16 + 4 * L45 * t ^ 2

    Console.WriteLine("1st Sum: " & Sum)

    Sum = t ^ 2 + LBase + 6 * t ^ 3 + 2 * LBase ^ 3 + 3 * LBase ^ 2 * t + 2 * LAdjacent ^ 2 * LBase + LAdjacent ^ 2 * t + 8 * LAdjacent * t * LBase + 4 * LAdjacent * t ^ 2 - LOpposite ^ 2 * LBase + LOpposite ^ 2 * t - 4 * LOpposite * t * LBase + 4 * LOpposite * t ^ 2

    Console.WriteLine("2nd Sum: " & Sum)
```

Both equations should be equivalent: I've simply replaced L16 with LBase, L23 with LAdjacent and L45 with LOpposite. Yet the first equation outputs 3586 while the second outputs 3587. Why?

I'm using VS2010

Amr

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the problem?

Comment: Hmm...I worked on the equations using Maple and the ones in the code are the output of its "simplify" command. I haven't tried to hand simplify it - I'll give it a go.

Comment: I bet the ^ operator doesn't do in vb what you think it does

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: ? It's the power operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Sum calculation:

```
Sum = t ^ 2 * L16 + ...
```

Second Sum calculation:

```
Sum = t ^ 2 + LBase + ...
```

One has `*`, where the other has `+` .